# Display list of user name with user points sorted by points based on certain time period?

Tags: views, 7, userpoints

We added user points for provide points to user, when creating node, comments and likes.

We created view for display user points list (user name, Total points, and ranks). It working fine.

But we need to display the above based on the certain period.

Thanks in advance. Provide any idea...

```
example
--------
1) From Jan-2013 to March-2013
------------------------------------
Rank   - Points  -  Name
-------------------------------------
1      - 50      -  user2
2      - 48      -  user1
3      - 40      -  user3
-------------------------------------

2) From April-2013 to June-2013
------------------------------------
Rank   - Points  -  Name
-------------------------------------
1      - 55      -  user3
2      - 54      -  user2
3      - 40      -  user1
-------------------------------------

3) From July-2013 to September-2013
------------------------------------
Rank   - Points  -  Name
-------------------------------------
1      - 55      -  user2
2      - 54      -  user3
3      - 40      -  user1
-------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

- In the contextual filter of the view add `Userpoints Transactions:
  User`
- In views fields add `Userpoints Transactions: Timestamp`. I see that you do not want to display date in views, so mark it as **Exclude from display**.
- In grouping setting of your view select `Userpoints Transactions: Timestamp`

Comment: sorry subhojit777. I not getting the solution. user name repeatedly coming in same time period

Comment: What is your view format?

Comment: View format is User

Comment: I am not asking the view type. I asked the view format (table, grid, HTML list, etc.). And its good that you mentioned the view type, I am not sure whether you will get the contextual filter that I mentioned in answer in a view of user type. Or you can search that in relationships. Or try creating the view with userpoints type.

Comment: Thanks friends.. I wrote raw php code this functionality.